# Change Height Constraint for View wrapped in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, snapkit

I have a UITableView with a custom cell that contains a view.

After the view is displayed, I want to change the hight of the nested view.

Im using the updateConstraints function of the SnapKit framework.

However, I get the error, that the updated constraint conflicts with the `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` that apparently comes from the initial set height.

```
    "<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x2807666a0@ViewController.swift#89 SnapKitTest.NestedView:0x102005ef0.height == 100.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x280766880@ViewController.swift#70 SnapKitTest.NestedView:0x102005ef0.top == SnapKitTest.TestCell:0x10280e200.top>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x280766940@ViewController.swift#70 SnapKitTest.NestedView:0x102005ef0.bottom == SnapKitTest.TestCell:0x10280e200.bottom>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280058a50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' SnapKitTest.TestCell:0x10280e200.height == 20   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x2807666a0@ViewController.swift#89 SnapKitTest.NestedView:0x102005ef0.height == 100.0>
```

Below is some source code to run a sample app:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let tableView = UITableView.init(frame: .zero)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(self.view)
        }

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "X")
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let c = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)) as? TestCell {
            c.nestedView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
                make.height.equalTo(100)
            }
        } else {
            print("didnt geht cell")
        }
    }

}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 5 {
            let c = TestCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

            return c


        }

        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "X")
        c?.backgroundColor = .orange
        return c!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }


}


class TestCell: UITableViewCell {
    let nestedView = NestedView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


        addSubview(nestedView)
        nestedView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(self)
        }
        backgroundColor = .blue

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


class NestedView: UIView {

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        backgroundColor = .yellow

        snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.height.equalTo(20)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: don't do it like that. set the constraints inside `cellForRowAt ` method and reload the table. and make sure you have `UITableView.automaticDimension`

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't wanna do that. And that won't work, as far as I know. You need to setup your constraints, either in your cell's `init`. Or in your `cellForRow` function.

So in my codes below, I modified yours, and I add a property (height constraint) of your `NestedView` inside your `TestCell` cell. And I update that height inside the `cellForRow`.

Edit: if you want to toggle a cell height, of course you do it the same way, you just need to reload the rows/sections or whole data of your tableView.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let tableView = UITableView.init(frame: .zero)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(self.view)
        }

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "X")
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 5 {
            let c = TestCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
            c.constraint_HeightOfNestedView?.update(offset: 100.0)
            return c


        }

        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "X")
        c?.backgroundColor = .orange
        return c!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
}
```

**TestCell.swift**

```
import SnapKit

class TestCell: UITableViewCell {
    var constraint_HeightOfNestedView: Constraint?
    let nestedView = NestedView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


        addSubview(nestedView)
        nestedView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(self)
            self.constraint_HeightOfNestedView = make.height.equalTo(20.0).priority(999).constraint
        }
        backgroundColor = .blue

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**NestedView.swift**

```
import UIKit

class NestedView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .yellow
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: You helped me a lot. In my case, the nested view was a UIImageView, and I called my custom cell.configure method to set the UIImageView.image and try to modify the height constraint in the same method without success. I took the height modification to another method and called It after calling configure, which solved my problem. Almost a complete day trying to solve it, until I found your answer!

Comment: That's great to know! :D

Answer (score 0):

To change the height of a subview In UITableViewCell you have to set the height of the desired view and also set the priority to 999. Off-course you have to use self sizing cells :)

Ex.
My requirement was,

```
UITableViewCell 
  -- contentView
     -- UIImageView (pinned to all sides in contentView)
```

Inside cellForRow,

```
let constraint = cell.myImageView.constraint(equalTo: cell.myImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2.0)//change multiplier as you need or directly set the height to any value
        constraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
        constraint.isActive = true
```